# @Async method get executed in spring boot even after execption in caller method

Tags: java, spring-boot

```
class ServiceImpl {
    @Autowired
    EmailService emailService;

    public void arr() throws Exception,CommonCustomException {
        int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
       try{
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length() + 1; i++) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
        }
       catch(exception e)
       {
          throw new Exception();
       }

     try{
        emailService.sendMail("Subject of mail", "body of mail", "xuz@gmail.com", "abc@gmail.com");
         }
     Catch(CommonCustomException e)
       {
           throw new CommonCustomException("Exception occured while sending 
                   mail");
       }
    }
}

@EnableAsync
class EmailService {
    @Async
    public void sendMail(String subject, String body, String from, String to) {
        // Implementation of sendMail function
    }
}
```

I have used `@Async` annotation in the email service for triggering the mail, if any error occurs in the caller method the mail is getting triggered irrespective of any exceptions in the caller method.

I don't want the email method to get executed after the error occurs in the caller method. how can I handle this?

In the above example, the for-loop throws arrayIndexOutOfBoundException even after the exception occurs the mail will get triggered since it is an async function. I don't want the mail to get triggered if an exception occurs in arr() method.

Comment: No the line with emailService.sendMail will not be reached when you have an Exception on the line with for. So no mail will be sent

Comment: This is just an example i have send you, In our code everything is enclosed inside a try catch block that is why it is throwing the Exception On use of @Async  it will create a separate thread and start to execute sendMail method so at that time we can't prevent this method from execution

Comment: @NivedithaPrakash Then perhaps you should change the example to show code that could actually make the problem you have occur. Right now, your problem cannot happen, so we'll be rejecting the question as "Not reproducible". --- While you are at it, please format (indent) the code for human readability.

Comment: @NivedithaPrakash why would you not have senEmail in the same try block? Although this example looks like it shouldn't send email.